# what is the updated and recommended manner to bold: use tag <strong> or font-weight in CSS?

Tags: html, css, bold

In a SEO perspective optimization, which one is better: Use HTML or CSS?

I searched in some contents and I didn't get a precise and updated answer.

Comment: You use both, a tag for the semantic meaning and CSS to make it look.

Answer (score 1):

##### `font-weight`:  Affects how the text looks in the browser.

##### `<strong>` : Gives syntactic significance to the text such that screen readers and web scrapers can use to understand which text is important.

---

`<strong>` is the standard used from `HTML 5`

You can just mimic `<strong>` using `font-weight:bold`